# Getting the hover and other effects to work

Tags: html, css

I cannot get my hover or the other effects to work properly. What part of my code is incorrect?

**CSS**

```css
#nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(https://bboard.mcckc.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1284576-dt-content-rid-6702240_1/courses/1141_PV_1_CSIS_128_13995/css-sprites.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#nav a {
    background: url ('https://bboard.mcckc.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1284576-dt-content-rid-6702240_1/courses/1141_PV_1_CSIS_128_13995/css-sprites.jpg') 0 0;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background: url ('https://bboard.mcckc.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1284576-dt-content-rid-6702240_1/courses/1141_PV_1_CSIS_128_13995/css-sprites.jpg') 0 -39px;
}

#nav a:active {
    background: url ('https://bboard.mcckc.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1284576-dt-content-rid-6702240_1/courses/1141_PV_1_CSIS_128_13995/css-sprites.jpg') 0 -83px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <a href="http://www.mcckc.edu"><img src="https://bboard.mcckc.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1284576-dt-content-rid-6702240_1/courses/1141_PV_1_CSIS_128_13995/css-sprites.jpg" /></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

your css is looking for an `a` tag inside of an id called `nav` but you dont have that in your html. Change it to

```
<div id="nav"><a href="http://www.mcckc.edu"><img src="https://bboard.mcckc.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1284576-dt-content-rid-6702240_1/courses/1141_PV_1_CSIS_128_13995/css-sprites.jpg" /></a></nav>
```

also you are trying to change the background of `a` but you have an image tag inside of the `a`. You should make everything a background image

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the white space between `url` and the opening parentheses in `url (...)`, as follows:

```css
#nav a {background: url('https://bboard.mcckc.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1284576-dt-content-rid-6702240_1/courses/1141_PV_1_CSIS_128_13995/css-sprites.jpg') 0 0;}
#nav a:hover {background: url('https://bboard.mcckc.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1284576-dt-content-rid-6702240_1/courses/1141_PV_1_CSIS_128_13995/css-sprites.jpg') 0 -39px;}
#nav a:active {background: url('https://bboard.mcckc.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1284576-dt-content-rid-6702240_1/courses/1141_PV_1_CSIS_128_13995/css-sprites.jpg') 0 -83px;}
```

**[WORKING](http://jsbin.com/mexaluqu/3/edit)** vs ***[NOT WORKING](http://jsbin.com/mexaluqu/2/edit)***.

Also as you've used `#nav a` selector, you should have a wrapper for the anchor tag with the id of `nav` as well. If there's not such a element in your real markup remove the `#nav` from the CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you're accessing the  element inside another element with an ID of "nav"... but in your HTML, there is no #nav element. You have two options, the first being:

1. Change your CSS to remove all the #nav before the a's.
2. Change your HTML to something like this:

   ```
   <div id="nav">
        <a href="http://www.mcckc.edu"><img src="https://bboard.mcckc.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1284576-dt-content-rid-6702240_1/courses/1141_PV_1_CSIS_128_13995/css-sprites.jpg" /></a>
   </div>
   ```

Also, as Hashem Qolami said, you should remove the white space between "url" and your opening parenthesee. On another note, make sure the url inside your parentheses is inside quotes as well.

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I'd do it, in its simplest form

**http://jsfiddle.net/7wh9z/**

Add your image paths as needed - I've used colours as an example, you can take them out if you need to.

```
<a href="#Link"></a>

a {background: url('') #ff0000; width:150px; height:45px; display: block}
a:hover {background: url('') #00ff00;}
a:active {background: url('') #0000ff;}
```

The fact you've got an image in there already means whatever is in your IMG tag will display above the background - So that will prevent you from seeing the background and hover effects, so you're best off taking that out.

Remember to give your links classes or ID's as what I've given you will affect all a tags.